# Populating some fields after selecting the element using Struts2-Dojo autocompleter

Tags: autocomplete, struts2, populate

I am using sx tag i.e. struts-dojo-tag of struts 2 to autosuggest one field on one page. It is working fine. Now I want to populate other fields on the same page based on the selection of autosuggest field. I tried calling javascript on the above field on various events like onselect, onchange,etc with no success.

JSP code :

<sx:autocompleter autoComplete="true" listKey="id" listValue="brandName" name="brand.brandName" id="brandName" cssClass="textfield" list="brandList" onchange="populateInfo(this.value);"></sx:autocompleter>

here I want to autosuggest brandNames available and on selecting the brand, I want to populate data regarding the brand in some others fields. I tried calling java script function populateInfo(), but the function is not getting called.

Can you please help me out?

Comment: Please provide some more  information. The information you have provided is not sufficient.

Comment: Why don't you use the <s:doubleselect />?

Comment: @lschin I want to populate number of other fields related to brand..like address line, city, zip code, etc, depending on the brand selected. Hence, I cant use double select.

Answer (score 1):

I think this problem can be solved by using **select** tag of **struts2-jquery**. 
You can have a look in these [showcase](http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action)